# mod_rewrite disallow url except certain cases in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a url so that all requests for /admin get a 404 except for admin/special_page and admin/another_special_page etc.

I think I need some regex magic to help, but I'm not sure?!

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to write this in your .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/special_page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/another_special_page
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

The first RewriteCond blocks every request to the "admin"-folder, the other two conditions exclude the two special pages. The RewriteRule will not change the URL but create a 404-error